# iOS AudioUnit Control - kAudioUnitSubType_Delay

Tags: ios, core-audio

I can setup real time playback and have the delay unit putting in between Remote IO Unit to set up a delay effect.

```
 AudioComponentDescription delayDesc;
 delayDesc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
 delayDesc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_Delay;
 delayDesc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
```

However, I could not find any parameters to set and control the effect of the Delay Unit. 
[Audio Unit Parameters Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioUnitParametersReference/Reference/reference.html)

I want to have the delay effect tuneable. For example, I want to delay time and fraction to be changed to see the difference. Any Hints?

Comment: @SamB, "Page Not Found" from the link you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check AudioUnitParameters.h

```
// Parameters for the AUDelay unit
enum {
        // Global, EqPow Crossfade, 0->100, 50
    kDelayParam_WetDryMix               = 0,

        // Global, Secs, 0->2, 1
    kDelayParam_DelayTime               = 1,

        // Global, Percent, -100->100, 50
    kDelayParam_Feedback                = 2,

        // Global, Hz, 10->(SampleRate/2), 15000
    kDelayParam_LopassCutoff            = 3
};
```

working example:
http://idev.by/ios/23137/

Comment: "Working example" gives 403 error. Internet Archive helps a bit: https://web.archive.org/web/20141219002215/http://idev.by/ios/23137/

Answer (score 0):

Hold `cmd` button and click on `kAudioUnitSubType_Delay`. You will see the following:

```
@constant       kAudioUnitSubType_Delay                 
                    - desktop only
                A delay audio unit
```

It seems it is of mac os only, not iOS